# Monodevelop Android download file

Tags: c#, android, save, download, monodevelop

I am using MonoDevelop for Android and would like some help to easily download a file from a URL, and then save it to a file. I have seen many Java versions of this action, but am after some C# code if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [docs to `WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).[`DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Sample from the docs:

```
string remoteUri = "http://www.contoso.com/library/homepage/images/";
string fileName = "ms-banner.gif", myStringWebResource = null;
// Create a new WebClient instance.
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
// Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
Console.WriteLine("Downloading File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\" .......\n\n", fileName, myStringWebResource);
// Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource,fileName);        
Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\"", fileName, myStringWebResource);
Console.WriteLine("\nDownloaded file saved in the following file system folder:\n\t" + Application.StartupPath);
```